# Getting A USB Monitor And It's Drivers To Work On A Headless Computer

Tags: usb, bios, headless

I'm creating a new computer set up and have ran into a snag: I can't get the Cubi to boot headless even with server software installed on it's hard drive.

**Hardware**

MSI Cubi 251US: [specs](https://icecat.ch/en/p/msi/cubi-251us/cubi-pcs-workstations-Cubi-251US-36534534.html)

Asus Zenscreen: [specs](https://www.asus.com/Monitors/ZenScreen-MB16ACE/specifications/)

Lenova Laptop (I'm using this to install software on the hard drive and ssh)

A usb keyboard and usb mouse are plugged into the Cubi.

**Software**

My Laptop: Ubuntu 18.10 installed on it, fully updated and upgraded.

The Cubi: Ubuntu 18.10 server installed on it, fully updated and upgraded.

**Description Of Situation:**

The ZenScreen is a usb external display and is not compatible with displaying bios. The Cubi only has a HDMI and Mini DisplayPort outlets. I do not have a HDMI/Mini DisplayPort monitor that would display the bios. So I must configure Cubi headless while the monitor is plugged in until I get it to work.

I used my laptop to install Ubuntu Server 18.10 on the hard drive.

I've enabled and tested that openssh-server is working on Cubi and a client from my laptop can connect by using a usb wifi card. My wifi card has a light that turns on once bios hands control over to Ubuntu boot process and Ubuntu loads network-manager. I inserted the hard drive into the Cubi and pressed the power button. I was thinking I would see the wifi light turn on but it didn't.

**The Plan**

If I get Cubi to boot with Ubuntu I will create an ssh connection with it with my laptop. I will install a desktop. Install the DirectLink drivers for the Zenscreen and configure it until it works.

**Theory**:

The bios is stopping the boot process because there is no display.

**Question:**

What is required to get this Cubi to boot headless so I can go in ssh and configure it to get ZenScreen working?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minicomputer

Comment: [mini-pc aka mini computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Mini_pc&redirect=no)

Comment: That article is a little sparse. And no it is not about mini computers. Smaller that a mini computer is a micro-computer. I have not heard of a nano computer, but there are single chip computers (well really, they need a few extra bits). And small board computers.

Comment: Do you think I should change the title? Google does show the type of computer I have when you search 'mini computer'. I don't want to mislead people.

Comment: Yes Maybe mini-PC (as you said) is a better name. A PC is already a micro-computer (smaller than a mini-computer), and mini means smaller. Smaller than a micro-computer seems about right.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes PCs require a keyboard to get through posting. Did you try plugging in a USB keyboard for the startup process?

Comment: I have both a usb keyboard and usb mouse plugged in. I will update my question.

Comment: Sorry that it didn't work...

Comment: You might be able to fool the system into thinking a screen is attached when it's not really. I remember doing this with a graphics card to mine bitcoin. The graphics card wouldn't come up unless there was an output attached but I was using it as a server, so I had to attach a DVI dongle with certain pins shorted. Not sure what you would have to do to get a similar effect with a usb, or if it would work.

Comment: A HDMI Dummy Plug,Headless Ghost, Display Emulator may very well be an answer to my problems, but I don't have one. They seem to be pretty inexpensive on Amazon so I will order one and get back to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am the poster and this solution is most certainly a hack but I was not able to get any of these commonly accepted solutions to work for Ubuntu 19.10:

- move hard drive with new installation into headless and boot
- [no questions asked preseed](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/NetworkConsole)
- [serial console install](https://github.com/ynkjm/ubuntu-serial-install/blob/master/README.md)

I created an Ubuntu live install usb stick. I took out the hard drive and places an extra usb stick in to do a mock install upon it. I took my tablet and took snap shots of the installation process. These snap shots were taken for reference purposes. I was careful to take note of usb read/write light activity on each step of the installation process.

I then plugged in install usb into the headless computer that had keyboard attached and powered it up. It was tricky getting past bios but I did. I plugged in the target hard drive for installation.

I then used the keyboard to do the install without seeing what actually was going on. I used tab and enter keys most of the time to move through the installer. Once at the user and password screen I used alphanumeric keys of course.

I then tried to boot my laptop up with the new usb installation. It worked. I installed the drivers for the DiplayLink monitor. I set the displaylink monitor as primary and removed all other monitors from being used. I powered down.

I placed the new installation usb into the headless but now with the DisplayLink monitor plugged in. It worked.